# issue with running a response client in Jupyter notebook

Tags: json, python-3.x, http, jupyter-notebook

I am running the below code for response client. The code is working perfectly fine when running in sublime or pycharm but it is not printing anything when running on the Jupyter notebook. May I please know what is going wrong? I think there is some dependency with Jupyter that needs to be imported. In both the cases I am using python version 3.6

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost:9000")

payload = "{\"key\" : \"value\", \"array\":[\"one\",\"two\"]}"

headers = {
'content-type': "application/json",
'accept': "application/json",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

conn.request("POST", "/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
if int(res.code) is 200:
    print("YES")

data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: What are the two python versions ?  (The one that works, the one that doesn't)

Comment: in both it is python version 3.6

Comment: Could it be sitting there in the `conn.getresponse()` waiting to timeout because of a network issue?